# React Native not firing Console.log

Tags: javascript, react-native, console, touchableopacity

I have this small sample react native code representing the main functionality of my original code. I am trying to console.log TouchbleOpacity onPress(). But the function is not firing anything on the console. Also, it does not console as soon as component mounts. Alert works fine, but this is not of concern.  Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export default class Terms extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component mounted');
  }

  submitData = () => {
    console.log('button pressed');
    alert('hiiiii')
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.submitData} >
        <Text> textInComponent </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried different methods for function binding also, but not able to figure out the problem. It seemed to be working fine before but not now. Kindly help with the fix.

Comment: Make sure you're connected to the debugger correctly

Comment: @Kai Yes it is connected properly. I tried restarting the debugger again and again, but still the same.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue. I am facing similar issue in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue I resulted to using `console.warn`. This appears as the YellowBox warning.
You can view your logs on the console also.
Here is an example screenshot.[image]

Comment: Did you used textInput also? Since for my original code, along with console.log, I am also sending the data from input to the database. And touchableOpacity does not seems to work for both of them (console + textInput data).

Comment: I am using TouchableOpacity whic onPress calls I used an anonymous function to call. In you code I did this `<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.submitData()} >`   When I did this the `console.log` was not fired but using `console.warn` everything logs well

Comment: console.warn does not seem to solve the purpose exactly. How about the case when a user is sending the value from textInput and want to console.log() that value and save that value to the database.

Comment: Why would the user want to console.log the value?